# How to send stdout/stderr to grandparent process?

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, shell, stdio

I have this node.js code:

```
 const k = cp.spawn('bash');

    k.stdin.end(`

        set -e;
        echo; echo; echo 'du results:';
        ( cd "${extractDir}" && tar -xzvf "${createTarball.pack.value}" ) > /dev/null;
        find "${extractDir}/package" -type f | xargs du --threshold=500KB;

    `);

    k.stdout.pipe(pt(chalk.redBright('this is a big file (>500KB) according to du: '))).pipe(process.stdout);
    k.stderr.pipe(pt(chalk.magenta('du stderr: '))).pipe(process.stderr);
```

the problem is that multiple grandchildren will write all it's stdout/stderr to the parent.

I want to do something like this instead:

```
 const pid = process.pid;

 const k = cp.spawn('bash');

    k.stdin.end(`


        set -e;

        exec 3<>/proc/${pid}/fd/1

        echo > 3 ; echo > 3; echo 'du results:' > 3;

        ( cd "${extractDir}" && tar -xzvf "${createTarball.pack.value}" ) > /dev/null;
        find "${extractDir}/package" -type f | xargs du --threshold=500KB ;

    `);

    k.stdout.pipe(pt(chalk.redBright('this is a big file (>500KB) according to du: '))).pipe(process.stdout);
    k.stderr.pipe(pt(chalk.magenta('du stderr: '))).pipe(process.stderr);
```

but that technique won't work on MacOS because Mac doesn't have the /proc/pid fs feature. Does anyone know what I am trying to do and maybe a good workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Install [libsys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsys) or some other means of making raw syscalls from node. Then, do the syscall [`dup(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) with `1` as its argument, and store the result to variable `fd`. Once you do that, `fd` will be a number of a file descriptor that's a duplicate of node's stdout, and it will be inherited by child processes. At that point, just remove `exec 3<>/proc/${pid}/fd/1` from bash, and replace all of your `>&3`s with `>&${fd}`s.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, probably too intricate for my needs which aren't that complex, I added an answer solving it a different way. I guess I would accept this answer if had a little bit more code showing how, that way it might in the off chance help some rando who reads this in 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this problem a different way, the OP was a bit of an XY question - so I basically use mkfifo since I am on MacOS and don't have a  `/proc/<pid>` file:

first we call this:

```
mkfifo "$fifoDir/fifo"
```

and then we have

```
    const fifo = cp.spawn('bash');
    fifo.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

    fifo.stdout
      .pipe(pt(chalk.yellow.bold('warning: this is a big file (>5KB) according to du: ')))
      .pipe(process.stdout);

    fifo.stdin.end(`

        while true; do
          cat "${fifoDir}/fifo"
        done

    `);

    const k = cp.spawn('bash');

    k.stdin.end(`

        set -e;
        echo; echo 'du results:';
        tar -xzvf "${createTarball.pack.value}" -C "${extractDir}" > /dev/null;
        ${cmd} > "${fifoDir}/fifo";
        kill -INT ${fifo.pid};

    `);

    k.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    k.stderr.pipe(pt(chalk.magenta('du stderr: '))).pipe(process.stderr);

    k.once('exit', code => {

      if (code > 0) {
        log.error('Could not run cmd:', cmd);
      }

      cb(code);
    });

  },
```

the "fifo" child process is a sibling process to process k, which is obvious when you look at the above code block, and the "fifo" process ends up handling the stdout of one of the subprocesses of the k process - they intercommunicate by way of the named pipe (mkfifo).